# Suggestion wanted for MFC custom scrollbars

Tags: mfc, scrollbar

I want to make my own scrollbars for a custom drawn plot, like this image, what would be the best way to go?

[image: Example]

Scrollbars should:

- Only be visible when mouse hover over it (with fade in/out)
- Be a part of the x/y axis of the plot, like in the picture
- Not have any arrow buttons, just the thumb Thinner than the normal scrollbars

Would you suggest to:

1. Create everything from scratch, handling paging, scrollwheel etc.
2. Try to inherit CScrollBar and do my own drawing?

From what I've read, it's not very easy to customize scrollbars in MFC, for example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120636/Roll-Your-Own-Scroll-Bar))

Comment: There already is a scrollbar in your screenshot. Why don't you customize that? Other than that, we have no information whatsoever, what control you want your scrollbars hosted in.

Comment: You really only have option 1, because standard scroll bars don't support owner draw and also draw outside of `WM_PAINT` / `WM_NCPAINT` as explained in the linked article. Option 1 won't be that complicated, but still a substantial effort. Trying to inherit from `CScrollBar` won't reduce the effort; on the contrary, it would be a non-trivial "hack" to fake owner-draw and much harder to maintain. For the fade in/out effect, have a look into [Buffered Animation API](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/vista/article.php/c15841/Using-the-Windows-VistaWindows-7-BuiltIn-Buffered-Animation-API.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, these have to be scrollbar (or other) controls, not window scrollbars (used for scrolling a window).

Second, the statement "it's not very easy to customize scrollbars in MFC", is only partially true. MFC is a "thin wrapper" of Windows API, so you should better refer to the documentation of the Windows scrollbar control.

Then there is the CScrollBar class, but took a short look, and indeed, it does not really offer anything more than the Windows scrollbar does. As for the sample in the link you posted is a new (custom) control (painting everything on its own), i.e. literally "from scratch", not inheriting anything from CScrollBar.

So, you have to look into the Windows scrollbar control, and what it offers. Did take a look, and saw few things. Unfortunately there seems to be no owner-draw functionality. You can process the `WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR` message, but this only allows you to change colors.

And according to the documentation the background color only. This appears to be the only possible customization, apart from the SBM_ENABLE_ARROWS message, which can hide the arrows. And no fading effect. If these are enough to you, you could try the Windows/MFC scrollbar, otherwise try writing your own.